# Shell command to enable auto-hide launcher

Tags: command-line, unity, launcher

I know launcher can be set to auto hide through system settings. But I want to do this using a shell command. Is this possible? I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This One:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ launcher-hide-mode 1
```

Comment: This is not working on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Think the gsettings has been updated to this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide false
```